# what is the name of this set? and how i prove this problem.

Tags: real-analysis

$$\mathcal{C}^{(i)}=\left\{ {(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^{2}}:x^{2}+y^{2}=i^2} \right\}$$
$$\mathcal{A}^{(i)}=\left\{ {(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^{2}}:CH\left( {\mathcal{C^{(i)}}} \right)} \right\}$$
$\mathcal{B}$ can be any bounded set, i.e.,
$$\mathcal{B}=\left\{ {(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^{2}}:CH\left( {[1,1],[1,-1],[-1,-1],[-1,1]} \right)} \right\}$$
where CH means the convex hull, and $\mathcal{A}^{(i)}$ is the expanding region of circle

How can I prove that $\lim\limits_{i \to \infty}\mathcal{A}^{(i)}$ becomes a superset of $\mathcal{B}$ at some iteration $1 \le i < \infty$ although this is intuitionally trivial.
Does $\lim\limits_{i \to \infty}\mathcal{A}^{(i)}$ become $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

What is the name of such set of $\lim\limits_{i \to \infty}\mathcal{A}^{(i)}$?
Is this unbounded set? or bounded set?

Since $\lim\limits_{i \to \infty}\mathcal{A}^{(i)}$ is unbounded set, $\lim\limits_{i \to \infty}\mathcal{A}^{(i)}$ becomes a superset of $\mathcal{B}$. Is this sentence can be a proof?

Answer (score 1):

For the first one:

- Show that $\mathcal{A}^{(i)}$ contains every point of norm $i$ or less;
- Show that every point in $\mathcal{B}$ has norm less than some maximum.

The limit is $\mathbb{R}^2$, in the sense that the $\mathcal{A}^{(n)}$ are strictly increasing as $n$ increases through $\mathbb{N}$, and every point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contained in some $\mathcal{A}^{(n)}$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your set $\mathcal{A}^{(n)}$ is simply a disk around the origin of radius $n$, i.e. $\mathcal{A}^{(n)} = \overline{B}((0,0),n)$.

Now it is clear that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{A}^{(n)} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{A}^{(n)} = \mathbb{R}^2$$

where 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{A}^{(n)} = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^2 : v \in \mathcal{A}^{(n)} \text{ for infinitely many }n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{A}^{(n)} = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^2 : v \in \mathcal{A}^{(n)} \text{ for all except finitely many }n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
Therefore we can say $\lim_{n\to\infty } \mathcal{A}^{(n)} = \mathbb{R}^2$. In particular, $\lim_{n\to\infty } \mathcal{A}^{(n)} \supseteq \mathcal{B}$.

Comment: inf means that bounded from below some value. how this can be $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @박수연 Let $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|(x,y)\| \le n_0$. Then for every $n \ge n_0$ we have $(x,y) \in \mathcal{A}^{(n)}$ so $(x,y) \in \liminf_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{A}^{(n)}$.

Comment: I am sorry for saying this. I have no experience in real analysis. I am studying the concept of the limit inferior and limit superior, but I can't get it clearly. could you explain this a little bit easier? or any reference cite helps me to understand

Comment: @박수연 This is the limit inferior of a sequence of sets, it is not the same as the limit inferior of a sequence of real numbers. For a sequence of sets $(S_n)_n$, the definition is 
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} S_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in S_n \text{ for all except finitely many } n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
and similarly for limit superior. So we could say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$ exists if $\liminf_{n\to\infty} S_n = \limsup_{n\to\infty} S_n$.

Comment: Now, I know $\lim\sup\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{A}^{(n)}=\lim\inf\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{A}^{(n)}$ is convergent to $\mathcal{A}^{(\infty)}$. However, how can we say  $\mathcal{A}^{(\infty)}=\mathbb{R}^{2}$?? thank you for you reply. Is it trivial?

Comment: convergent -> divergence

Comment: @박수연 In my comment above I showed that an arbitrary point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is contained in $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{A}^{(n)}$. Hence $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{A}^{(n)} = \mathbb{R}^2$. The same argument sa above shows $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{A}^{(n)} = \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I understood a bit now, so Let $\mathbf{x}\in{\mathbb{R}^{2}}$ and let $n_{0}\in{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\mathbf{x}\in{\mathcal{A}^{(n_{0})}}$. Then for every $n>n_{0}$ we have $\mathbf{x}\in{\mathcal{A}^{(n)}}$ since $\mathcal{A}^{(n)}$ is monotonically increasing. Therefore, $\mathbf{x}\in{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{A}^{(n)}}=\mathbb{R}^{2}$. In particular, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathcal{A}^{(n)} \supseteq\mathcal{B}$ can be complete proof for my question?

Comment: @박수연 Yes, if it is clear what you mean by $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathcal{A}^{(n)}$.